# npm install only works when package is globally installed

Tags: node.js, npm

I am on a Windows 10 machine and can only install npm packages globally. From the command prompt I can run:

> npm install -g mocha
>
> mocha

And there is no problem. When I install the package locally and run the command I receive the following error.

> npm install mocha
>
> mocha
>
> 'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file..

Comment: That's the way NPM works.  The global installation path is the only path added to the environment variables.  If you want to run something from a local install, try doing `npm run <package>`, so for your example, `npm run mocha`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) you will be able to use the binaries from the local installations. Simply add a script to your `package.json` file:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  }
  ...
}
```

And then to run it, simply do:

```
npm run test
```

For some commands, there are aliases, for example you can do `npm start` instead of `npm run start` and `npm test` instead of `npm run test`. But for all other scripts, you will have to do `npm run <name>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way NPM works. The global installation path is the only path added to the environment variables. If you want to run something from a local install, try doing `npm run <package>`, so for your example, `npm run mocha`

Answer (score 0):

With a local installation of mocha, you can invoke it with:

`node_modules/.bin/_mocha`

try `node_modules/.bin/_mocha -h`

Caveat - You have to be in the directory where you installed it.